# Can't output elements from List<int>

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

I need to add some integers to `ArrayList` before 1-st average wouldn't be higher or a bit lower than in 2-nd average. But in the end , where I need to output all elements I can't do that. I've try use `List<>` instead of `ArrayList` but I had problems with output.

Here's my code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;

 namespace Marks
 {
    internal class Program
    {
        public static float AverageOfArrayList(ArrayList Array)
        {
            float AverageOfArrayList = 0;
            float Sum = 0;

            foreach (int item in Array)
            {
               Sum += item;
            }
            AverageOfArrayList = Sum / Array.Count;
            return AverageOfArrayList;
        }
        public static ArrayList GetVariables(ArrayList NewMarksList, float CurrentAverage, double MissedAverage)
        {
            if (CurrentAverage > MissedAverage)
            {
               for (int i = 0; MissedAverage < AverageOfArrayList(NewMarksList) ; i++)
               {
                  NewMarksList.Add(2);
               }
            }

            if (CurrentAverage < MissedAverage)
            {
                  for (int i = 0; AverageOfArrayList(NewMarksList) < MissedAverage; i++)
                  {
                     NewMarksList.Add(5);
                  }
            }
            return NewMarksList;
      }
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          float CurrentAverage = 0;
          double MissedAverage = 0;
          ArrayList CurrentMarksList = new ArrayList();


          Console.WriteLine("Enter how much marks have you got");
          int CountOfMarks = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

          Console.WriteLine("Enter the 1-st average");
          CurrentAverage = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

          Console.WriteLine("Enter the 2-nd average");
          MissedAverage = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

          ArrayList newList = GetVariables(CurrentMarksList, CurrentAverage, MissedAverage);
          List<int> OutputArray = newList.Cast<int>().ToList();

          Console.WriteLine("Marks to add :");

          for (int OutputCounter = 0; OutputCounter < OutputArray.Count; OutputCounter++)
          {
              Console.Write(OutputArray[OutputCounter] + " ");
          }
          Console.ReadKey();
      }
   }
}
```

Inputs which i used to test program:

```
 CountOfMarks = 5;
 CurrentAverage = 3,4;
 MissedAverage = 3,8;

 Output = Nothing
```

Comment: Can you add what inputs are given to this program and what is the expected output?

Comment: "had problems with", can you be more specific? What kind of problem?

Comment: I can see a big problem in your loops inside the GetVariables method. The _NewMarksList_ is empty at the first iteration. This means that the division in AverageOfArrayList (Sum / Array.Count) is 0/0 and produces NaN. Still it is totally unclear what are you trying to achieve here. So perhaps you should explain better what is the purpose of this code.

Comment: @Lasse When I output my List or ArrayList it always clear.

Answer (score 0):

It was eaiser if you could give also an example for input, what you expected and what happens in reality.

This is how I initialized the parameters:

```
CountOfMarks = 3  
CurrentAverage = 4  
MissedAverage = 5
```

By the way there is no need to pass an empty list to a function and then return a new list.
You can declare the empty list inside the function as local variable.

There are two big problems with this code:


## Dividing number by zero


Inside `GetVariables(...)` you used `AverageOfArrayList(NewMarksList)`.
The problem is that you are passing an empty array to this function.
The count of the empty array is zero and **you divided a number with zero** (`Sum / Array.Count`) which is **illegal**.

So you can't send an empty array to `AverageOfArrayList(...)`.

I  solved it by just adding `o_NewMarksList.Add(...)` before the `for` loop and increment the index to `i = 1` as an alternative.
This will keep you for sending an array with at list one element.
I also declared the empty list as a local variable.

## Unchangeable condition in For loop cause infinite loop


You put in the condition of the `for` loop an average which will always be the same.
In the first loop the average will always be 2 and in the second loop it always will be 5.
This will cause the loops to run infinitely.
In order to solve this we need to understand what you realy wanted to do.

**Alternative solution (solving only the dividing by zero)**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Marks
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static float AverageOfArrayList(ArrayList Array)
        {
            float AverageOfArrayList = 0;
            float Sum = 0;

            foreach (int item in Array)
            {
                Sum += item;
            }
            AverageOfArrayList = Sum / Array.Count;
            return AverageOfArrayList;
        }
        public static ArrayList GetVariables(float CurrentAverage, double MissedAverage)
        {
            ArrayList o_NewMarksList = new ArrayList();
            if (CurrentAverage > MissedAverage)
            {
                o_NewMarksList.Add(2);
                for (int i = 1; MissedAverage < AverageOfArrayList(o_NewMarksList); i++)
                {
                    o_NewMarksList.Add(2);
                }
            }

            if (CurrentAverage < MissedAverage)
            {
                o_NewMarksList.Add(5);
                for (int i = 1; AverageOfArrayList(o_NewMarksList) < MissedAverage; i++)
                {
                    o_NewMarksList.Add(5);
                }
            }
            return o_NewMarksList;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float CurrentAverage = 0;
            double MissedAverage = 0;



            Console.WriteLine("Enter how much marks have you got");
            int CountOfMarks = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the 1-st average");
            CurrentAverage = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the 2-nd average");
            MissedAverage = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            ArrayList newList = GetVariables(CurrentAverage, MissedAverage);
            List<int> OutputArray = newList.Cast<int>().ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Marks to add :");

            for (int OutputCounter = 0; OutputCounter < OutputArray.Count; OutputCounter++)
            {
                Console.Write(OutputArray[OutputCounter] + " ");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT (30.11.2016):**
**Second try:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Marks
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static float AverageOfArrayList(ArrayList Array)
        {
            float AverageOfArrayList = 0;
            float Sum = 0;

            foreach (int item in Array)
            {
                Sum += item;
            }
            AverageOfArrayList = Sum / Array.Count;
            return AverageOfArrayList;
        }
        public static ArrayList GetVariables(float CurrentAverage, double MissedAverage)
        {
            ArrayList o_NewMarksList = new ArrayList();
            if (CurrentAverage >= MissedAverage)
            {
                o_NewMarksList.Add(2);
                for (int i = 1; MissedAverage < AverageOfArrayList(o_NewMarksList); i++)
                {
                    o_NewMarksList.Add(2 + i);
                }
            }

            if (CurrentAverage <= MissedAverage)
            {
                o_NewMarksList.Add(5);
                for (int i = 1; AverageOfArrayList(o_NewMarksList) < MissedAverage; i++)
                {
                    o_NewMarksList.Add(5 + i);
                }
            }
            return o_NewMarksList;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float CurrentAverage = 0;
            double MissedAverage = 0;

            //Console.WriteLine("Enter how much marks have you got");
            //int CountOfMarks = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the 1-st average");
           // CurrentAverage = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the 2-nd average");
          //  MissedAverage = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


            //ArrayList newList = GetVariables(CurrentAverage, MissedAverage);
            ArrayList newList = GetVariables(3, 3);
            List<int> OutputArray = newList.Cast<int>().ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Marks to add :");

            for (int OutputCounter = 0; OutputCounter < OutputArray.Count; OutputCounter++)
            {
                Console.Write(OutputArray[OutputCounter] + " ");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this will fix the NaN problem,  but the problem is even worse now. The code enters an infinite loop now if you use something more bigger like 12 and  42 for the two inputs. Do you have any idea on what the OP wants to do here? Me no.

Comment: In other words. If you insert in an empty array 100 times the value 5, what is the average? And when this average will allow the code to exit from the loop condition?.

Comment: Yes.You right.
The problem is that he puts in the condition an average which will always be the same.
In the first loop the average will always be 2 and in the second loop it always will be 5.
I also don't know what he wants to do but the condition of the for loops must be change.

Comment: @E235 Example what I want : I have five marks and my average is 3,4 so I want to get average 3,8. And I want to count how much marks I could add

Comment: @MatvieiSkufin in your code you are not using "CountOfMarks". You just get this input from the user and doesn't do something with this.

Comment: I don't understand.
Example, your CurrentAverage is 3 and your MissedAverage is 3.
You sent both of them to GetVariables(3,3).
At this point you will check if(CurrentAverage > MissedAverage) => false.
Then you will check if(CurrentAverage > MissedAverage) => false.
So you will return an empty array.
Maybe you wanted to do ">=" instead of ">" ? 
I edited the answer, check "Second try:".